# Поиск по БД - Данные не найдены

Tags: c#, sql, запрос

Есть БД, сделал по ней поиск.
Все работает как надо.
Если записи по нужному году есть, то выводит и НАПРИМЕР в лейбле пишет "Записи за 2018 год".
Но если записей нет, как записать в лейбл записи не найдены?! Именно проверку на пустоту?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода:

```
            labelListFound.Text = "Список уголовных дел за " + numericUpDownYear.Value.ToString() + " год";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MainWindow.connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select NumberCriminalCases AS '№ у/д' , Article AS 'Статья', DateIntination AS 'Дата возбуждения у/д', Subdivision AS 'Подразделение', FIOEmployee AS 'ФИО Сотрудника', NumberCRB AS '№ КУСП', DateCRB AS 'Дата КУСП', Fabula AS 'Фабула', Revealed AS 'Раскрыто', LimitationDate AS 'Срок' From dbo.ListOfCriminalCases Where YEAR(DateAdded) = {0}", numericUpDownYear.Value), conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgvArchive.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: Может как то проверить именно ДатаГрид на пустоту?

Comment: Раз вы сделали поиск, то вы знаете,  когда записей нет, вот в этот момент и пишите в лейбл что хотите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете проверять количество элементов коллекции `Rows` в экземпляре `DataTable` после заполнения его адаптером.

```
da.Fill(dt);
conn.Close();
if( dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
//запись в лейбл что ничего не найдено
}
else
{
dgvArchive.DataSource = dt; //что-то нашлось, вывели на грид
}
```